# Convert seconds into hh:mm:ss format using moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am trying to convert seconds in hh:mm:ss format . 
I have using below code to convert seconds into hours,min.
but I don't want to do all this. Is it possible in moment.js to convert seconds into HH:MM:SS format. rather than doing it manually.

```
var x = 43000
var durationValue = moment.duration(x, 'milliseconds');
var hours = Math.floor(durationValue.asHours());
var mins = Math.floor(durationValue.asMinutes()) - hours * 60;
console.log("hours:" + hours + " mins:" + mins);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
moment("1900-01-01 00:00:00").add(43000/1000, 'seconds').format("HH:mm:ss")
```

try this?

moment's duration doesn't have millisec in their definition, you should divide it by 1000.

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Comment: Can you please describe moment("1900-01-01 00:00:00") . I am not getting why we have provided this.

Comment: `moment("1900-01-01 00:00:00")` is just a dummy date but want to have a valid moment object. `moment("2016-09-20 00:00:00")` should work too. We're not interested in the date part.